# Reading Lua nested tables in C++

Tags: c++, c, lua, lua-table, nested-table

I'm creating a C/C++ function which will be called from Lua. My function must call a library function who's signature is like this:

```
void libFunction( int val1, int val2, tSETTINGS * pSettings );
```

I'm given these C/C++ structs:

```
typedef struct
{
    int cmd;
    int arg;
} tCOMMAND;
typedef struct
{
    int numberCommands;
    int id;
    tCOMMAND commands[1];
} tSETTINGS;
```

Maybe my thinking is all wrong on this, but from Lua I'm calling like this:

```lua
id   = 42
val1 = 1
val2 = 2
cmd1 = { 3, 4 }
cmd2 = { 5, 6 }
commands = { cmd1, cmd2 }
settings = { #commands, id, commands }
mycfunction( val1, val2, settings )
```

I'm sure that I'm still not understanding the Lua stack as referenced from C++, since what I'm trying just doesn't work. My solution is able to retrieve `val1`, `val2`, `#commands` and `id`, but when I try to retrieve `commands[0]` and `commands[1]` I get `{1, 2}` and `{2, 42}` respectively.

My C++ is essentially like this (for this sample I'm discarding the values). I've already retrieved `val1` and `val2`:

```c
int stkNdx = 1;
lua_rawgeti(L, 3, stkNdx++ );
int numcmds = lua_tointeger(L, -1);  // this successfully retrieves numberCommands 2
lua_pop(L, 1);
lua_rawgeti(L, 3, stkNdx++ );
int id = lua_tointeger(L, -1);       // this successfully retrieves id 42
lua_pop(L, 1);

lua_pushvalue(L, -1 );
lua_pushnil(L);
int cmdNbr = 0;
for( lua_next(L, -2); cmdNbr < numcmds; cmdNbr++ )
{
    lua_pushvalue(L, -2);
    int cmd = lua_tointeger(L, -1);
    int arg = lua_tointeger(L, -1);
    lua_pop(L, 2);
    lua_next(L, -2);
}
lua_pop(L, 1);
```

I've tried various permutations of `lua_rawgeti()` followed by `lua_tonumber()` and `lua_pop()`, with basically the same result.

This seems similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6137684/iterate-through-lua-table), and my solution is modeled after that with no success.

Experimenting more I inserted this:

```c
lua_pushnil(L);
while( lua_next(L, -2) )
{
    if( ! lua_istable(L, -1) )
    {
        int v = lua_tointeger(L, -1);
    }
    lua_pop(L, 1);
}
```

This loop executes 4 times.  The first 2 times the values 2 and 42 are assigned to `v`. The next 2 iterations skip the assignment (lua_istable returned true).  So it seems that although I've already retrieved `numcmds` and `id`, they're still there on the stack. I also clearly don't understand how to iterate over the subtables when they're encountered.

Comment: I've tried doing that too some time ago and ended up writing https://github.com/d-led/luastackcrawler . Once you crawl the stack, you can get out the table, taking care of circular references as well, but I do not have a sufficient test yet to show that it works. You might want to contribute. Try it out :). The place to start: [luavalue.h](https://github.com/d-led/luastackcrawler/blob/master/luatablestack/luavalue.h)

Answer (score 6):

Lua table indices range from [1 .. N] instead of [0 .. N-1].

Your loop should be:

```
int cmdNbr = 1;
for( lua_next(L, -2); cmdNbr <= numcmds; cmdNbr++ )
{
  ...
}
```

or as I prefer it:

```cpp
lua_rawgeti(L, 3, 2 );
int id = lua_tointeger(L, -1);       // this successfully retrieves id 42
lua_pop(L, 1);

lua_rawgeti(L, 3, 3);
{
    // commands table at stack top
    size_t N = lua_objlen(L,-1); // size of the table
    
    for (int i = 1; i <= N; ++i)
    {
        lua_rawgeti(L,-1, i); // cmd# at stack top
        {
            lua_rawgeti(L,-1,1); // first entry
            int cmd = lua_tointeger(L,-1);
            lua_pop(L,1);
            
            lua_rawgeti(L,-1,2); // second entry
            int arg = lua_tointeger(L,-1);
            lua_pop(L,1);
        }
        lua_pop(L, 1); // pop cmd#
    }
}
lua_pop(L, 1); // pop commands table
```

Note that, with the function `lua_objlen(L,idx)`, it's not necessary to pass `numcmds`.

Comment: which means that cmd1 and cmd2 should also range from [1..2]

Comment: Thank you SO much.  I *think* I understand ... will try it out tomorrow and then hopefully I *will* understand.  Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks *Enigma* ... that worked perfectly ... no changes at all to what you suggested.  Better still, I think it understand it.  Thanks for adding comments to your suggested code.

Comment: Dmitri ... I'll see if I can use what I've learned from *Enigma* and contribute.