# How can I read and write to nested lua tables from C++?

Tags: c++, lua, lua-table, lua-api

I have a nested table in my lua code that I want to pass to C++ so the native code can manipulate it:

```lua
-- Some persistent data in my game
local data = {
        { 44, 34, 0, 7, },
        { 4, 4, 1, 3, },
}
-- Pass it into a C++ function that can modify the input data.
TimelineEditor(data)
```

How do I write my C++ code to read the nested table and modify its values?

*[Reading Lua nested tables in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16975760/reading-lua-nested-tables-in-c) and [lua c read nested tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27037854/lua-c-read-nested-tables) both describe how I can read from nested tables, but not how to write to them.*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reading Lua nested tables in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16975760/reading-lua-nested-tables-in-c)

Comment: That question is only about reading tables, not writing to them.

Comment: you can consider including sol libraries to your project. it will make life easier

Comment: Correct, although I'm sure anyone that can get that far can figure out to use `lua_rawseti` instead of `lua_rawgeti`. And since there are questions on how to read nested tables (and writing to regular tables), there really isn't a need for this question? But fair I guess.

Comment: There are [3 other q/a with rawseti](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=rawseti) and they're either about non-nested tables or creating new tables. I made the connection to rawseti, but it took awhile to figure out the details. I think this question would be very helpful to anyone trying to understand how the lua C API works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Short answer

Lua uses a stack to get values in and out of tables. To modify table values you'll need to push the table you want to modify with `lua_rawgeti`, push a value you want to insert with `lua_pushinteger`, and then set the value in the table with `lua_rawseti`.

When writing this, it's important to visualize the stack to ensure you use the right indexes:

```
lua_rawgeti()
    stack:
        table

lua_rawgeti()
    stack:
        number <-- top of the stack
        table

lua_tonumber()
    stack:
        number
        table

lua_pop()
    stack:
        table

lua_pushinteger()
    stack:
        number
        table

lua_rawseti()
    stack:
        table
```

Negative indexes are stack positions and positive indexes are argument positions. So we'll often pass -1 to access the table at the stack. When calling `lua_rawseti` to write to the table, we'll pass -2 since the table is under the value we're writing.

## Example

I'll add [inspect.lua](https://github.com/kikito/inspect.lua) to the lua code to print out the table values so we can see that the values are modified.

```lua
local inspect = require "inspect"

local data = {
        { 44, 34, 0, 7, },
        { 4, 4, 1, 3, },
}
print("BEFORE =", inspect(data, { depth = 5, }))
TimelineEditor(data)
print("AFTER =", inspect(data, { depth = 5, }))
```

Assuming you've figured out [BindingCodeToLua](http://lua-users.org/wiki/BindingCodeToLua), you can implement the function like so:

```cpp
// Replace LOG with whatever you use for logging or use this:
#define LOG(...) printf(__VA_ARGS__); printf("\n")

// I bound with Lunar. I don't think it makes a difference for this example.
int TimelineEditor(lua_State* L)
{
    LOG("Read the values and print them out to show that it's working.");
    {
        int entries_table_idx = 1;
        luaL_checktype(L, entries_table_idx, LUA_TTABLE);
        int n_entries = static_cast<int>(lua_rawlen(L, entries_table_idx));
        LOG("%d entries", n_entries);
        for (int i = 1; i <= n_entries; ++i)
        {
            // Push inner table onto stack.
            lua_rawgeti(L, entries_table_idx, i);
            int item_table_idx = 1;
            luaL_checktype(L, -1, LUA_TTABLE);
            int n_items = static_cast<int>(lua_rawlen(L, -1));
            LOG("%d items", n_items);
            for (int i = 1; i <= n_items; ++i)
            {
                // Push value from table onto stack.
                lua_rawgeti(L, -1, i);
                int is_number = 0;
                // Read value
                int x = static_cast<int>(lua_tonumberx(L, -1, &is_number));
                if (!is_number)
                {
                    // fire an error
                    luaL_checktype(L, -1, LUA_TNUMBER);
                }
                LOG("Got: %d", x);
                // pop value off stack
                lua_pop(L, 1);
            }
            // pop table off stack
            lua_pop(L, 1);
        }
    }

    LOG("Overwrite the values");
    {
        int entries_table_idx = 1;
        luaL_checktype(L, entries_table_idx, LUA_TTABLE);
        int n_entries = static_cast<int>(lua_rawlen(L, entries_table_idx));
        LOG("%d entries", n_entries);
        for (int i = 1; i <= n_entries; ++i)
        {
            // Push inner table onto stack.
            lua_rawgeti(L, entries_table_idx, i);
            int item_table_idx = 1;
            luaL_checktype(L, -1, LUA_TTABLE);
            int n_items = static_cast<int>(lua_rawlen(L, -1));
            LOG("%d items", n_items);
            for (int j = 1; j <= n_items; ++j)
            {
                int x = j + 10;
                // Push new value onto stack.
                lua_pushinteger(L, x);
                // rawseti pops the value off. Need to go -2 to get to the
                // table because the value is on top.
                lua_rawseti(L, -2, j);
                LOG("Wrote: %d", x);
            }
            // pop table off stack
            lua_pop(L, 1);
        }
    }
    // No return values
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
BEFORE =    { { 44, 34, 0, 7 }, { 4, 4, 1, 3 } }
Read the values and print them out to show that it's working.
2 entries
4 items
Got: 44
Got: 34
Got: 0
Got: 7
4 items
Got: 4
Got: 4
Got: 1
Got: 3
Overwrite the values
2 entries
4 items
Wrote: 11
Wrote: 12
Wrote: 13
Wrote: 14
4 items
Wrote: 11
Wrote: 12
Wrote: 13
Wrote: 14
AFTER =     { { 11, 12, 13, 14 }, { 11, 12, 13, 14 } }
```